# Comparison between an EPOCH time form server and date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm developing a Spring boot application frontend and the server is passing to me database record with a value, representing the date, that is EPOCH time so: "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'"

I would need to filter only date that are same date of today.

So how can I transform to a standard date format and comparison with date of now?

many thanks

Comment: That's not "epoch time", it's an ISO standard UTC date. You can pass it directly to the JavaScript Date constructor.

Comment: While use of the built–in parser is [generally discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Examples), you've chanced upon the only supported format that is reliably parsed by implementations currently in use, so `new Date(timestamp)` will do.